# _Static_assert with __has_include

Tags: c

I wanna make macro, that checks that file is "includable".
Something like this:

```
#define CHECK(__file)    \
    _Static_assert( __has_include(__file), "Error")
CHECK("header.h");
```

But it produces errors like

```
f.c:28:3: __has_include must be used within a preprocessing directive
f.c:28:3: Implicit declaration of function '__has_include' is invalid in C99
f.c:28:3: Static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
```

Is this even possible? Or maybe there is different solution that will give similar result?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to spare two lines of `#if / #endif`?

Comment: Also note that the use of `__has_include` is not *standard* in C, as it is in C++17, albeit support by compiler vendors exists. Thought I'd mention this since you've tagged `C`.

Comment: Names starting with two underscores are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. You should not even use them as macro paramter names. And `_Static_assert` is **not** a preprocessor function! And from the error messages: you seem to compile as C99, but `_Static_assert` was introduced with C11. You should get the standards correct first.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually, I wanted to make it as part of another macro to assert "existence" of specific file. Anyway, it is not related to question above.

Comment: @DeiDei what tags do I need then?

Answer (score 0):

If all fails (and you can hardly argue with: "__has_include must be used within a preprocessing directive"), throw another layer of indirection at it:

```
h_assert(){
    for h; do
printf '
#if !__has_include("%s")
_Static_assert(0,"__has_include(\"%s\")");
#endif
' "$h" "$h"
    done
}
h_assert foo.h bar.h baz.h #Generate the header assertions with a POSIX shell
```

Comment: It is not a problem to write extra lines of code. `CHECK()`  should be part of another macro, that is doing some another work, but should assert users if there is no such include.

Comment: @AlfredZien `__has_include` needs to come after an `#if` directive and you can't make a macro that expands to an `#if` directive (or any preprocessing directive for that matter). Hence the need for another layer.